# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with MKNetworkEngine

Tags: ios, xcode6.1, mknetworkkit

I'm using `MKNetworkkit` to parse XML data to the server. Before Entering into the success block its gets crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with out any reason and am already done with `NSZombieEnabled` like all the stuffs.![Below is the screen shot of where its getting crash.][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL3l9.png

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful to help debug http://subhb.org/2012/07/02/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-error/

> You will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error mostly in the following scenarios:
>
> - You are trying to access an object that is not initialized.
> - You are trying to access an object that no longer exists. Either it’s    being released or it’s nil. In ARC mode, make sure you take
>     ownership    of the object that you want to use.
> - You are passing an message to an object that the object doesn’t    understand. It can also happen for bad typecast.

Have you tried running breakpoints on your code and stepping through your program line by line and seeing if any of the above match the result?

Comment: Yes..i have check with the breakpoint. After enable with zombies getting following as the reason '-[NSPathStore2 length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7bb7a920'

Comment: Is NSPathStore2 null?

Comment: No. If enabling zombies am getting above crash report. Otherwise, no reason..its just struck with that line.

Comment: You may have to post some more code for me to further understand why its crashing.